# How to respond to duplicate Realtime payment updates

Tags: facebook, callback, payment

We did a setup for realtime payments endpoint, and things seems to be working just fine. There was no major difference for PayPal / Credit card payments, as we are receiving a confirmation from client much faster than "realtime" update. For our country, mobile payments are instant, too. However by analyzing our logs, we found that some payments take longer time to proceed.

Most notable exception is the Philippines users (hi there, you've got a beautiful country) trying to pay by mobile. Other users are from Brazil and India (hi there, i hope to visit Taj Mahal and Rio carnival someday) Facebook keeps posting action update for such payments. We already completed the in-app purchase on our side, but Facebook keeps posting these realtime updates. Do we have to do something in order to stop it? Is this a normal behaviour? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I fear that the users of [so] won't be able to help you with this one. You might have to get in contact with Facebook. [so] does not operate as Facebook's customer support...

Comment: Anyway, thanks for paying attention to my question. Yes, I asked facebook about this, but their response is typically very slow, and also I'm not 100% sure we did not missed something.

Comment: If you say that all the payments are working correctly and some are just taking longer than others then I think it is safe to say that your system is not the problem here.